# Get the username with django profileserializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I developed api with django. I created a code structure like below.
How do I get the user's first_name and last_name in class ProfileSerializer?

that is, with ProfileSerializer, I want to get information such as the user's name, surname, id number

``

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, Serializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'userKey', 'phone', 'email', 'address', 'userState')

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(instance=instance.profile, data=profile)
        profile_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        profile_serializer.save()
        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

``

Comment: Can you show the models? General answer - by using [serializermethodfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) or by using proper type fields with setting [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute

Comment: Consider to Upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define [**`serializers.CharField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) as,

```
class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name' read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'userKey', 'phone', 'email',
                  'address', 'userState', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your serializer like this

```
class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'userKey', 'phone', 'email', 'address', 'userState')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data.update({'username': instance.userKey.username, 'first_name': instance.userKey.first_name, 'last_name': instance.userKey.last_name})
        return data
```

Comment: data.update({'first_name': instance.userKey.first_name, 'last_name': instance.userKey.last_name})
AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'first_name'

I get an error like this. can you help me ?

Comment: what is relation between `Profile` and `User`?